# Inject REQUEST provider

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm working on a personal project using `NestJS` along with `@nestjs/cqrs` ,`fastify` and `@fastify/secure-session`.

I'm trying to follow a CLEAN architecture so I uncouple interfaces, entities, use-cases, and infrastructure, but this leads me to some problems with `NestJS`, I was able to solve them all until now.

I'm currently working on a Sign In Session Use Case, where a user can sign into his account. So I created everything that was needed, use-case, interfaces (services interfaces), services (user service, cryptography service, and the special one session service), and controller (infrastructure).
I connected the controller with the use-case using `cqrs`, so I created a command and a command handler, and everything else was tied up with the standard `nestjs` module definition. So this way I end up with something like this (I used this recipe before on another use-case so it is proven that everything works from the controller to the service):

[image]

The main problem began when I try to inject the REQUEST provider into a service, specifically, the session service, I'm using the `fastify-secure-session` so I need to access the request to manage the session, I read all about injecting the REQUEST provider, from updating the scope to `Scope.REQUEST`, to injecting the request using the the `ModuleRef` but I'm not getting how to inject correctly the request, and every time I try the request it's undefined.

My files looks like this:

Controller:

```
@Controller('sessions')
export class SessionController {
  constructor(private readonly commandBus: CommandBus) {}

  @Post()
  signIn(@Body() signInDto: SignInDto) {
    return this.commandBus.execute(
      new SignInCommand(signInDto.email, signInDto.password),
    );
  }

  @Delete()
  signOut(@Body() signOutDto: SignOutDto) {
    return this.commandBus.execute(new SignOutCommand(signOutDto.email));
  }
}
```

CommandHandler:

```
@CommandHandler(SignInCommand)
export class SignInCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<SignInCommand> {
  constructor(
    private readonly moduleReference: ModuleRef,
  ) {}

  async execute(command: SignInCommand): Promise<Session> {
    const sessionUseCase = await this.moduleReference.resolve(SessionUseCase);
    return await sessionUseCase.signIn(command.email, command.password);
  }
}
```

Use-case:

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionUseCase {
  constructor(
    private readonly cryptographyService: ICryptographyService,
    private readonly userService: IUserService,
    private readonly sessionService: ISessionService,
  ) {}

  async signIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<Session> {
    const user = await this.userService.findByEmail(email);
    const doesPasswordMatch = await this.cryptographyService.compare(user.password, password);

    if (!doesPasswordMatch) {
      throw new InvalidSessionCredentialsException();
    }

    this.sessionService.destroy();
    return this.sessionService.create(user.email);
  }

  async signOut(): Promise<void> {
    return this.sessionService.destroy();
  }
}
```

And session service:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class SessionService implements ISessionService {

  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: FastifyRequest,
    private readonly cryptographyService: ICryptographyService
  ) {}

  create(email: string): Session {
    this.request.session.set('email', email);
    this.request.session.set('id', this.cryptographyService.id());
    return this.request.session.data();
  }

  destroy(): void {
    this.request.session.email = null;
    this.request.session.id = null;
    this.request.session.delete();
  }
}
```

I already tried everything that it's shown on this [page](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref), also I tried to inject the request the way the page says and to resolve the session service using the module ref, but I'm not able to make it works.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to fix it?

Comment: do you get any errors or is just that `@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: FastifyRequest,` is undefined?

Comment: I don't get any error until I make a request, because the request is undefined

Comment: Are you using the nest.js fastify adapter?

Comment: Also I'm looking at these docs wondering whether the problem is actually the request and not the moduleRef: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

I believe you've run into a known limitation of NestJS, reported here back in 2019: https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/issues/60. Quote:

> [T]he problem is that every CqrsModule provider is statically scoped which mean that they cannot depend on request-scoped providers. Once you define your command handler as a request-scoped provider, either CommandBus or QueryBus won't be able to reference it.

Basically, commands will not work with request-scoped providers.

## The workaround

Store the request object in "continuation-local storage" (CLS)! I've been using this alternative solution successfully in a number of my own projects and it is also the first suggestion on the issue thread.

CLS is a type of shared storage for your "call stack". With CLS, all methods in the call stack that are higher up than a given starting point, have access to the same data, yet the data is never passed from method to method as an argument. Convenient!

For example, let's assume the following chain of function calls: A() -> B() -> C() -> D() -> E(). Basically, if method B initiates a CLS namespace and stores a value "x" in there, then "x" will be available to methods C, D and E without being passed as an argument to any of these methods, *even* if the calls are asynchronous! Once B exits, this CLS namespace is destroyed and "x" is gone.

This allows you to easily implement request-scoping without having to rely on `Scope.REQUEST`. There's also the benefit that your `Injectable`s will not have to be re-instantiated every time there's a new request.

## The demo

I've put together an example for you using my favorite library named cls-hooked: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked. It's old but still works great. Unfortunately, the example uses Express as I don't work with Fastify, but I am sure this translates well.

```
// cls.service.ts
// This is the magic service.

import { Injectable, Module, NestMiddleware } from "@nestjs/common";
// Your main tool here.
import cls from "cls-hooked";
import type { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

const CLS_NS_ID = "my-app";

const CLS_REQUEST = "REQUEST";

@Injectable()
export class ClsService {
    private readonly cls = cls;

    // This method initiates a new CLS namespace / scope.
    // We will call it in NestJS's middleware. This way 
    // all methods called from that point onwards will have
    // access to the request object.
    run(callback: () => void) {
        const ns = this.cls.getNamespace(CLS_NS_ID) || this.cls.createNamespace(CLS_NS_ID);
        ns.run(() => callback());
    }

    // Our middleware will use this method to store the request
    // object in CLS.
    setRequest(request: Request) {
        if (this.getRequest()) {
            // If you ever get this, something is wrong.
            throw new Error("Cannot override request stored in CLS");
        }

        this.set(CLS_REQUEST, request);
    }

    // Our services will use this method to access the request
    // object stored in CLS.
    getRequest(): Request {
        return this.get(CLS_REQUEST);
    }

    private get(key: string): any {
        return this.getActiveNamespace()?.get(key);
    }

    private set<T>(key: string, value: T) {
        return this.getActiveNamespace()?.set(key, value);
    }

    private getActiveNamespace() {
        const ns = this.cls.getNamespace(CLS_NS_ID);
        if (ns?.active) {
            return ns;
        }
        console.error("No active CLS namespace");
    }
}

// ---
// cls.module.ts
// ---

// Make sure this gets imported wherever there's a need to access
// the request object.
@Module({
    providers: [ClsService],
    exports: [ClsService]
})
export class ClsModule {}

// ---
// cls.middleware.ts
// ---

@Injectable()
export class ClsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(private readonly cls: ClsService) {}

    use(request: Request, __: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        // Here we create a new CLS namespace...
        this.cls.run(() => {
            // ...store the request object in that namespace...
            this.cls.setRequest(request);
            // ...and proceed to the next middleware. From here-on
            // this.cls.getRequest() will return the request object.
            next();
        });
    }
}

// ---
// session.service.ts
// ---

// Note that there is no longer a need for { scope: Scope.REQUEST }
@Injectable()
export class SessionService implements ISessionService {

  constructor(
    // Just import this...
    private readonly cls: ClsService,
    private readonly cryptographyService: ICryptographyService
  ) {}

  create(email: string): Session {
    // ... and use it!
    this.cls.getRequest().session.set('email', email);
    this.cls.getRequest().session.set('id', this.cryptographyService.id());
    return this.request.session.data();
  }

  destroy(): void {
    this.cls.getRequest().session.email = null;
    this.cls.getRequest().session.id = null;
    this.cls.getRequest().session.delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 

I replaced the cls-hooked with the experimental AsyncLocalStorage module. And it worked perfectly.